# Wicket datepicker disappears on component update

Tags: java, jquery, datepicker, wicket

I have DateTextField component in a panel and it has datepicker declared in header javascript .

I have to make this component visible on change of a dropdown choice once we make `setVisble(true)` the DataTextField appears without datepicker, I tried couple of testing but it went in vain.

Culd anyone get through this?
Below is java code 
`

```
final DateTextField iDExpDateStringField = new DateTextField("iDExpDateField", new PropertyModel<Date>(this,
                        "customer.iDExpDateString");

                customerTypeChoice.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {          
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                        if(customerType = 30){
                            iDExpDateStringField.setVisible(false);
                        }else{
                            iDExpDateStringField.setVisible(true);
                        }
                        target.addComponent(iDExpDateStringField);
                    }
                }
```

`
Below is html code:

```
<label for="idDate"><wicket:message key="idDate" /><span class="required">*</span></label> 
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" size="10" wicket:id="iDExpDateField" id="birthDate" style="width: 150px;" />
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  $('#iDExpDateField').datepicker( { 
    'changeMonth' : true, 
 'changeYear' : true, 
 'yearRange' : '-100:+0', 
 'maxDate':'0',
    'showOn': 'both', 
    'dateFormat' : 'dd/mm/yy', 
    'buttonImage': 'images/calendar.gif', 
'buttonText' : 'Choose Date', 
    'buttonOnlyImage': true, 
     'fixFocusIE': false, 
 onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {this.fixFocusIE = true; 
 $(this).blur().change().focus();}, 
 beforeShow: function(input, inst) { 
var result = $.browser.msie ? !this.fixFocusIE : true; 
this.fixFocusIE = false;return result;}} ); 
});
```

Comment: You need to post your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `iDExpDateStringField.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)` after the instantiation of `iDExpDateStringField`. This is needed because if initially the component is invisible, i.e. not rendered at all, then Wicket cannot find it in the DOM and replace it when it becomes visible.

Comment: I don't see it in your question. What else do you spend us?